# What is the difference between IP and GeoIP?

Tags: geolocation, ip, ip-address, geoip

Is GeoIP the IP address of the ISP servers and not end user?

I had in my mailing list 5 people with the same geoIPs but their "regular" IPs were all different and even from different subnets.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the geo IP for a specific city or country but the normal IP is for every house, device, or whatever.